# Implementation of Binary Search Tree using linked list in javascript

Tags: node.js, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I want to ask that is implementing a BST and implementing it with linked list are the same ? For example, to implement a binary search tree, we have to create a node with information of its left and right child, similar is the situation when we use the linked list as a node consists of three parts such as data, left and right child. Then what is the difference ? Thank you minds in advance.

I implemented the BST and applied inorder traversal and searched the elements. But I find it difficult to imbibe the relation between binary search tree and the linked list. Correct me please.

Comment: (The tag *arrays* does not seem to pertain, and node.js marginally, if that. There is a tag [tag:doubly-linked-list] as well as [tag:binary-search-tree].)

Comment: The nodes linked in each node of a linked list are not commonly designated *child*. I prefer *successor* (and, for a *doubly* linked list, *predecessor*, much as a *parent* link is optional in tree nodes). In a *search* tree, there is a promise about keys in the subtrees in relation to a node's key; in a list, nodes not even need to have a key.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the links is different in binary search trees and doubly-linked lists.

In a doubly-linked list, the left link of one node is the inverted right link of another node (and vice versa):

```
1 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> 4
```

In other words, we always have

```
left(right(node)) = node
```

if `node` has a `right` link and

```
right(left(node)) = node
```

if `node` has a `left` link.

But the search tree

```
  2
 / \
1   4
   / \
  3   5
```

the node 4 is connected to *three* links: one incoming and two outgoing, and we have

```
left(right(2)) = left(4) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

### Double Linked List

Linked List is **linear data structure**. As [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-linear-and-non-linear-data-structures/) says:

> Data structure where data elements are arranged sequentially or
> linearly **where each and every element is attached to its previous and
> next adjacent** is called a linear data structure. In linear data
> structure, single level is involved. Therefore, we can traverse all
> the elements in single run only. Linear data structures are easy to
> implement because computer memory is arranged in a linear way. Its
> examples are array, stack, queue, linked list, etc.

```
Item_1 <--> Item_2 <--> Item_3 <--> Item_4 <--> Item_5 <--> Item_6 <--> Item_7
```

### Binary search tree

Binary search tree is non-linear data structure. As [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-linear-and-non-linear-data-structures/) says:

> Data structures where data elements are not arranged sequentially or
> linearly are called non-linear data structures. In a non-linear data
> structure, single level is not involved. Therefore, we can’t traverse
> all the elements in single run only. Non-linear data structures are
> not easy to implement in comparison to linear data structure. It
> utilizes computer memory efficiently in comparison to a linear data
> structure

```
                 8
                / \
               3   10
              / \    \
             1   6    14
                / \     \
               4   7     15
```